# How to print pdf file on server asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, process

i try print pdf file on server side.Now i have pdf file already and i try this code to print it.

```
Process printJob = new Process();
                    printJob.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
                    printJob.StartInfo.Arguments = printerName;
                    printJob.StartInfo.Verb = "printto";
                    printJob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    printJob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    PrinterSettings setting = new PrinterSettings();
                    setting.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
                    printJob.Start();
                    printJob.Close();
```

this code work find on localhost but not work on server side . Can you help me please? And solve this problem. Thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried to share your printer on the server so that you can connect him with your localhost and set him to default?

Comment: Yes already but it slienly.